# Why am I unable to add an origin to my Git configuration?

Tags: git, github

I have a folder on my PC which is a GIT project, and I want to see the source code.

I am following these steps on git bash:

1. Change into the directory where your source code is located in the command prompt.
2. First, create a new repository in this directory **git init**. This will say "Initialized empty git repository in ....git" (... is the path).
3. Now you need to tell Git about your files by adding them to your repository. Do this with git add filename. If you want to add all your files, you can do **git add .**
4. git remote add origin git@github:Myusername/repositoryname.git

And I get an error:

```
error: remote origin already exists.
```

What should I do to get these folders on GIT?

Any other idea to take a look in to source code of these folders?

I already tried changing 4th step into:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/Myusername/repositoryname.git
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you already have remote origin in your local git repository.
You can check it using below command.

```
git config --list --local
```

If you want to update remote origin, first you need to remove it using below command.

```
git remote remove origin
```

Then you can try your 4th step.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/Myusername/repositoryname.git
```

And you said that you want to see the source code of GIT project.
So you don't need to follow your steps.
You can see branches using below command.

```
git branch -a
```

Then you can work on existing branch or new cloned branch.
So if you want to work existing branch, you need to switch to it.

```
git switch <branch_name>
```

But if you want to clone new branch from existing branch, you can use checkout command.

```
git checkout -b <new_branch_name> <remote_name>/<remote_branch_name>
```

Comment: I got this error message:
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Myusername/repositoryname.git

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful for me to understand... I might need to know which branch and which file contains the code....that is the real problem!,

Comment: New repos tend to have `main` as the default branch, instead of `master`. You can also see which branch you're on with `git branch`; the current one will be highlighted.